# Using generics in actions to return different DTOs

Tags: c#, generics, asp.net-web-api

I want to return different DTOs from the 1 action. I have managed to do this by sending in a query string `detailLevel` and doing switch/case on the value to return different DTO types. This isn't ideal, as I want to do this on most of my GET actions. Ideally, I want my Action to be a generic method, and end up looking something like this:

```
[HttpGet("{detailLevel=Minimal}")]
[DetailLevelAttribute]
public HttpResponseMessage Get<T>()
{
    IEnumerable<T> schools = this.schoolService.GetAllSchools<T>(); ;

    return Request.CreateResponse<IEnumerable<T>>(HttpStatusCode.OK, schools);
}
```

My best guess on how to accomplish this is with the use of an `ActionFilterAttribute` that will do the switch/case stuff in `OnActionExecuting` and then call the action using the type determined by the value of `detailLevel`, but I'm not sure how to call/modify the requested action inside an `ActionFilterAttribute` (or if this is even the best way to do this).

Comment: You can create a class that inherits from `IHttpActionSelector` and replace the original one in your web api. That class decides which action is called. http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/extensibility/configuring-aspnet-web-api

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. How would I implement that to call Get<T>? It's the Specifying of the `T` part that I'm having difficulties with.